# Cypress Code Coverage: Merge E2E and Component Testing into same coverage report

Tags: javascript, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul

I have configured Cypress on my React Application and am using both E2E and Component Testing. Code Coverage is setup on both the tests using istanbul and @cypress/code-coverage.

The report is being generated for the individual tests. The issue comes up when I run once test type after the other.
For example, if I run E2E test the coverage report is generated. Then when I run component test, a new coverage report is generated that replaces the previous report.

Here is my cypress configuration,

Cypress version: 12.17.2

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000",
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      require("@cypress/code-coverage/task")(on, config);

      return config;
    },
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "create-react-app",
      bundler: "webpack",
      webpackConfig: {
        mode: "development",
        devtool: false,
        module: {
          rules: [
            // application and Cypress files are bundled like React components
            // and instrumented using the babel-plugin-istanbul
            // (we will filter the code coverage for non-application files later)
            {
              test: /\.js$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
                  plugins: [
                    // we could optionally insert this plugin
                    // only if the code coverage flag is on
                    "istanbul",
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      require("@cypress/code-coverage/task")(on, config);

      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

**cypress/support/e2e.js**

```js
import "./commands";
import "@cypress/code-coverage/support";
```

**cypress/support/component.js**

```js
import "./commands";
import "@cypress/code-coverage/support";
```

**.nycrc.json**

```js
{
  "all": true,
  "excludeAfterRemap": true,
  "include": ["src/**/*.js"],
  "exclude": ["cypress/**/*.js"]
}
```

Is there configuration that will make the 2 reports merge rather than replace each other?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the --report-dir option to set where you want the report to go

```
    npm run e2e-test1
    npx nyc report --reporter=json --report-dir=./coverage/test1/
    
    npm run e2e-test2
    npx nyc report --reporter=json --report-dir=./coverage/test2/
```

That'll generate a 'coverage-final' file in the directories specified.

Then you can use istanbul-merge to merge the files into one json report file called 'all-tests-coverage' for example, like so

```
npx istanbul-merge --out ./coverage/all-tests-coverage.json ./coverage/test1/coverage-final.json ./coverage/test2/coverage-final.json
```

Now you can generate the html report from that merged json file

```
npx istanbul report --include ./coverage/all-tests-coverage.json --dir ./coverage/all-tests-report html
```

Comment: Sounds feasible, but how to do it when nyc isn't called directly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure cypress is calling nyc in the background, so instead of having to directly generate the reports yourself, you can just tell cypress to not overwrite the previous collection. So, something like

`cypress run --env product=first`
`npx nyc --no-clean cypress run --env product=second`

In this example, you would tell the second run NOT to clean the results from the first. Then the report that is automatically generated by cypress should just merge the next test into it. 

I hope that makes sense. You still need to use nyc, but you're not generating the reports manually

Comment: Istanbul provides more details on how to get this done here: See combining-reports-from-multiple-runs https://bestofjs.org/projects/istanbul

Comment: Would that be the same instance of nyc though?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The package will still cobble together the proper coverage, regardless of how many separate times you run the `npx nyc` command. Could you clarify your question please?